# Files are not changing when I update them via FTP

Tags: caching, file-upload, ftp, webserver, host

I made some changes to a CSS file, uploaded it and saw no change. I cleared my browser's cache, repeated the process and still nothing. I also tried another browser and then experimented with other files - all the same result.I then deleted the CSS file altogether - the website still looks the same and I can still see the files in the browser's console.

I can only get results if I actually change the file names altogether (which is really inconvenient). I dont think there is an issue with FTP overwriting the file as there are no errors in FileZillas logs.

Is there another way a website can cache its self? Would anyone know why this is occurring?

EDIT:

I also tried this in cPanel's File Manager and viewed it on another PC - same result

Comment: I would like to know this too! I use filezilla, and sometimes, I would have to clear my history, close browsers, and reload the page. To get a change. It started to happen quite recently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Squid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29) and other web accelerators often sit between a hosted server and your browser. Although they are supposed to invalidate their caches when the backing file changes, that information isn't always sent to specification or acted on properly.

Indeed, there can be multiple caches between you and the server each of which has a chance of hanging onto old data.

Comment: Thanks! You are correct! In my case it was CoudFlare caching the site!

Answer (score 0):

**First**, use Firebug or "Inspect Element" in chrome.
Verify that the css file that the browser is loading the file you think is should load.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can cache things, did you try SHIFT-F5 on your webpage to force a reload of everything?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the main server has cached configuration setup to other servers, check with your IT department. If this is the case, you need to tell them to invalidate the cache through all the cached servers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with fileZilla to solve it you need to clear the file zilla cache or change the name of the files you are uploading.

Open FileZilla and click on the Edit menu.
Choose Clear Private Data.
In the new dialog box, check mark the categories you’d like to clear: Quickconnect history, Reconnect information, Site Manager entries, Transfer queue.
Finally, click OK to validate